# Undefined Method Paginate for Searchkick Results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, will-paginate, searchkick

> undefined method `paginate' for

Unable to Paginate when using searchkick

```
if params[:search].present?
     @courses = Course.search(params[:search]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 3)
else
     @courses = Course.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 3)
end
```

When the conditional skips to else. it can render and paginate no problem. But when it is subject to search it refuses to paginate. It seems to be due to the Searchkick gem, this problem does not arise when using regular dumb search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass pagination params as `#search` parameters:

```
@courses = Course.search(params[:search], page: params[:page], per_page: 3)
```

https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#pagination

Comment: It give me "undefined method merge" now

Comment: What is the params[:search] ? Give me an example of its value.